# Linq: group and select from collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class:

```
public class LevelInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string HexColor { get; set; }
        public string Caption { get; set; }
        public int MinPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a collection of `LevelInfo`. For example, we have the following data:

```
Id     HexColor     Caption     MinPrice
1       color1       name1         10
2       color2       name2         20
3       color2       name3         10
4       color3       name4         10
```

I want to get new collection of `LevelInfo` grouped(not exactly, don't know how to say properly) by HexColor.
For the data above I want to get the following collection that contain 3 records:

```
Id     HexColor     Caption     MinPrice
1       color1       name1         10
3       color2       name3         10
4       color3       name3         10
```

We not select record with `Id` equals 2 because we have `color1` (with `Id` =1) and it's have min price.
How can I do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to group, order *within* the group by MinPrice, and then select the first element from each group, right? If that's correct, you want:

```
var query = from level in levels
            group level by level.HexColor into levels
            select levels.OrderBy(level => level.MinPrice).First();
```

Alternatively, if you use [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) you can avoid doing a complete *sort* by `MinPrice`, just picking the value with the minimum price:

```
var query = from level in levels
            group level by level.HexColor into levels
            select levels.MinBy(level => level.MinPrice);
```